# AZCaptcha base64 decode images for German Embassy

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to make a program that decodes base64 images, sends the request to an AZCaptcha server, and puts the answer to the label that I want.

When I go to [this website](https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/appointment_showMonth.do?locationCode=pris&realmId=362&categoryId=591) I see that the captcha is base64 encoded, and the ID is changeable every time when I press the button Load another picture. In this site there are no unique IDs.

The code should have four functions: one that gets the exact ID (ID is not unique, when you refresh the website, it changes the ID of captcha), another that sends this ID (ID of captcha when I will open the website), to the server, and a third that puts the answer from AZCaptcha server to the next label.

Here are two functions that are used to send and parse the request to the server:

```
function sendToAPI(base64) {
    base64 = encodeURIComponent(base64);
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://azcaptcha.com/in.php",
        data: "method=base64&key=" + apikey + "&body=" + base64,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        onload: function(response) {
            var responseString = response.responseText;
            GM_log("Debug(Send): " + responseString);
            if (responseString == "ERROR_WRONG_USER_KEY" || responseString == "ERROR_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST" || responseString == "ERROR_ZERO_BALANCE" || responseString == "ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE" || responseString == "ERROR_TOO_BIG_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE" || responseString == "ERROR_WRONG_FILE_EXTENSION" || responseString == "ERROR_IMAGE_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED") {
                userLog("There has been a pretty severe error:" + responseString + ", you should disable the plugin and report this.", "error");
                throw new Error("Stopping execution");
            } else if (responseString == "ERROR_IP_NOT_ALLOWED" || responseString == "IP_BANNED") {
                userLog("For some reason your IP has been banned from the service. You should disable the plugin and report this.", "error");
                throw new Error("Stopping execution");
            } else if (responseString == "ERROR_NO_SLOT_AVAILABLE") {
                userLog("The server is at maximum capacity, we are resubmitting in 15s.", "warning");
            } else {
                userLog("Captcha sent, awaiting response", "success"); //Should really if this to deal with other responses sooner
                setTimeout(parseResponse, 15000, responseString);
            }
        }
    });
}
//Parse the response from the server
function parseResponse(prevResponse) {
    var captchaID = prevResponse.split("|");
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://azcaptcha.com/res.php?key=" + apikey + "&action=get&id=" + captchaID[1],
        onload: function(response) {
            var getResponse = response.responseText;
            if (getResponse == "CAPCHA_NOT_READY" || getResponse == "CAPTCHA_NOT_READY") {
                userLog("Captcha is not ready yet. Let's wait 10 seconds", "warning");
                captchaID = null;
                setTimeout(parseResponse, 10000, prevResponse);
                //Deal with errors
            } else if (getResponse == "ERROR_KEY_DOES_NOT_EXIST" || getResponse == "ERROR_WRONG_ID_FORMAT") {
                userLog("Fatal error! We have to quit out of the script. The error was: " + getResponse, "error");
                throw new Error("Stopping execution");
            } else if (getResponse == "ERROR_WRONG_CAPTCHA_ID") {
                userLog("Our ID is wrong, so the server is probably having issues. Wait 15s and attempting resubmit.", "warning");
                setTimeout(checkBotcheck, 15000);
            } else if (getResponse == "ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE") {
                userLog("Server thought the captcha was unsolvable, so we're going to resend it.", "warning");
                setTimeout(checkBotcheck, 5000);
            } else {
                GM_log("Debug(Response): " + getResponse);
                //Assuming we're all good
                var captchaArray = getResponse.split("|");
                var captchaAnswer = captchaArray[1];
                submitToCaptcha(captchaAnswer);
                count++;
                setTimeout(userLog, 3000, "We think the botcheck is: " + captchaAnswer + ". We are going to wait 15 seconds to see if it was. We have attempted to solve " + count + " botchecks (including retries).", "success");
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to make an code, that sends to the server, the exact ID of the image, gets the response from the server, and puts the answer to next label.

Can you help me somehow to solve this problem?